# Cannot Resolve Method getListView and setListAdapter (Android)

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

When I try to use either of the methods listed in the title (getListView() and setListAdapter()), I get an error that says the methods cannot be resolved.

Here is my code:

```
 public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    mFriendsRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);
    mFriendsRelation.getQuery().findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> friends, ParseException e) {
            List<ParseUser> mFriends = friends;
            String[] usernames = new String[mFriends.size()];
            int i = 0;
            for(ParseUser user: mFriends){
                usernames[i] = user.getUsername();
                i++;
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getListView().getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, usernames);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }


    });
```

This is inside of a class called MainActivity.

Comment: your `MainActivity` must extends `ListActivity`....

Comment: Please extend your class with ListActivity instead of Activity.

Answer (score 9):

your `MainActivity` must extends `ListActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
```

Go to this [Android List View](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) for more information.