# How to use setListAdapter when MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android

I'm new to android and following a 2014 Lynda tutorial to make a ListView using an adapter. Here is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView output;
    ProgressBar pb;
    List<MyTask> tasks;

    List<Flower> flowerList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Initialize the TextView for vertical scrolling
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        output.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_do_task) {
            if (isOnline()) {
                requestData("http://services.hanselandpetal.com/secure/flowers.json");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Network isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void requestData(String uri) {
        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        task.execute(uri);
    }

    protected void updateDisplay() {
       FlowerAdapter adapter = new FlowerAdapter(this, R.layout.item_flower, flowerList);
        setListAdapter(adapter); //<---Here is the error

    }
```

At `setListAdapter(adapter) I get`Cannot resolve method` error.

I know from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26714889)  that if MainActivity extends `ListActivity` instead of `AppCompatActivity` this error is resolved. But then I get many other errors that I'm unable to resolve. So appreciate your solution.

In case you needed, here is the `FlowerAdapter` class

```
public class FlowerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Flower> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Flower> flowerList;

    public FlowerAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Flower> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.flowerList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_flower, parent, false);

        //Display flower name in the TextView widget
        Flower flower = flowerList.get(position);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(flower.getName());

        return view;
    }

}
```

And here is the ListView that I've created in content_main.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="" />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.flowershop.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/id_content_main"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Do you a layout file for MainActivity? If yes, you must have created a `Listview` in it. Get a reference to this list view and set the adapter as listview.setAdapter(adapter)

Comment: ListView should not be used anymore. Instead use the new `RecyclerView`. There is a good developer guide for it. [See here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 yes, I have a MainActivity and and a ListView in it.

Comment: @MuratK. is ListView deprecated? If not, why not use it anymore?

Comment: @Karlom Check my answer. Tell me if it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create ListView in your activity_main.xml:

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

and use it:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Try the tutorial: http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90

or this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm

Comment: well, when I added the two lines into `updateDisplay` method, I get `Cannot resolve 'listView'`. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Karlom change `R.id.list` to `R.id.listView`

Answer (score 1):

Your `ListView` is inside `content_main` layout and not directly a part of `activity_main`.

Give an id to your `content_main` layout as:

```
<include 
    android:id="+id/id_content_main"
    layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Then access it like this

```
View contentView = findViewById(R.id.id_content_main);
listView = (ListView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Well, first I needed to correct `+id...` to `@+id...` then, still get `Cannot resolve 'listView'`.

Comment: @Karlom Post activity_main.xml

Comment: just added  `activity_main.xml` to the quesiton.